# Computing a piecewise-linear approximation of a function of three variables

Tags: math, linear-regression, least-squares, approximation

Imagine that you have a bunch of points in R3, each with a value (say, temperature). You want to construct a regular grid in R3 and compute a value at each grid point, such that if you then use trilinear interpolation at each of the input points, the computed values will minimize the least-squares error to the actual values. In other words, you'd like to figure out a set of values at regular grid points that will best approximate the actual data points you have.

There are several [papers](https://www.golovchenko.org/home/pwl_fit) and [implementations](https://jekel.me/2018/Continous-piecewise-linear-regression/) for the 1D version of this problem. Does anybody have any pointers to how to solve the 3D version?

With further reading, I think I need to use a [polyharmonic spline](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Polyharmonic_spline).

Comment: Hi. Are you sure you want **trilinear** interpolation, and not just linear interpolation? Just to make sure we give the same meaning to these words, could you expand a bit on how you'd use the grid to calculate the temperature at a given point in the grid? For instance if you have the 8 temperatures at the eight vertices of a unit cube, and you have a point (x, y, z) inside this cube, what formula would you use to calculate the temperature of this point ?

Comment: Hi Stef. For 3-space, you need to interpolate across all three dimensions, hence https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Trilinear_interpolation.

Comment: Well that's an unfortunate choice of vocabulary. And the wikipedia page doesn't even have a warning "not to be confused with ...". https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bilinear_interpolation doesn't have the warning either. Even though this "bilinear interpolation" is definitely a linear, and not a bilinear, application.